# SQL Server Agent shutting down minute after starting

Tags: sql, agent

I'm a noob :) to SQL , so please don't judge me to harsh

When I start SQL Server Agent it's shutting down minute after starting . I tried to set Alerts to send email. After I configured Database Mail , I was able to send test email , however after that SQL Server Agent started to misbehave.

When I deleted alerts, SQL server agent stays on , can I send notification throw TSQL and not use alerts from SQL server Agent ?

After examine Error Log :

Error,[LOG] Failed to send notification email to operator

Error,[441] SQLiMail API send mail failure

Error,[440] SQLiMail send mail failure (reason: )

Error,[298] SQLServer Error: 14607 profile name is not valid [SQLSTATE 42000]

Warning,[396] An idle CPU condition has not been defined - OnIdle job schedules will have no effect

Warning,[474] Unable to refresh Database Mail profile . (reason: No mail profile defined)

my guess is that a problem with Database Mail that I configured, or May be some issues with security restriction

Please help.

Comment: Can you post the configuration of your mail profile?

Comment: I used [wizard](http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2013/02/sql-server-database-mail.html) _italic_ **bold** `code` to config Database mail , do i use tsql code to see the configuration

Comment: Ok, but we need to see your individual configuration.  That is, the settings you used when performing these steps.